# Memory leak in JNI code

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, ipc

Below is the JNI code to bridge the Linux MQ between the C and Java processes. Although I have released all ArrayElements, the VIRT of top command stills showing a huge value. The max heap size was set to 2GB, but top showing VIRT is 10GB after 100 hours of execution. It looks like a memory leak to me, however, I can't figure out which part of the JNI code is causing the problem. Would be nice if someone can help me a bit on this. Thanks.

My JDK version is 1.8.0_91

**This is the mq_receive method I wrote**

```
JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_test_ipc_impl_LinuxMessageQueue_mq_1receive(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject self, jint mqdes, jbyteArray buffer, jint msglen) {
    jbyte* buf = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, buffer, NULL);
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env))
        return -1;

    struct timespec timeout;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeout);
    timeout.tv_sec += 1;

    int size = mq_timedreceive(mqdes, (char*) buf, msglen, 0, &timeout);

    if (size == -1) {
        if (errno == ETIMEDOUT) {
            size = 0;
        } else {
            perror("mq_receive fail");
        }
    } else {
        (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, buffer, 0, size, buf);
        if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env))
            return -1;
    }

    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, buffer, buf, JNI_COMMIT);
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env))
        return -1;

    return size;
}
```

**And, this is the mq_send method I wrote**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_test_ipc_impl_LinuxMessageQueue_mq_1send(
        JNIEnv *env, jobject self, jint mqdes, jbyteArray buffer, jint msglen) {
    jbyte* buf = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, buffer, NULL);
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env))
        return;

    if (mq_send(mqdes, (char*) buf, msglen, 0) == -1) {
        perror("mq_send fail");
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, buffer, buf, JNI_COMMIT);
    if ((*env)->ExceptionCheck(env))
        return;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here's the meaning of the flags](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.zos.80.doc/diag/understanding/jni_mode_flag.html) you pass to `ReleaseByteArrayElements` as the last parameter:

> The possible settings of the mode flag are:
>
> **0** Update the data on the Java heap. Free the space used by the copy.
>
> **JNI_COMMIT**
>   Update the data on the Java heap. Do not free the space used by the copy.
>
> **JNI_ABORT**
>   Do not update the data on the Java heap. Free the space used by the copy.
>
> The ‘0' mode flag is the safest choice for the Release call. Whether the copy of the data was changed or not, the heap is updated with the copy, and there are no leaks.

So, in your `mq_receive` function, call `ReleaseByteArrayElements` passing 0 as the final parameter. You don't need the `SetByteArrayRegion` call because the data will be copied back by `ReleaseByteArrayElements`.

In your `mq_send` function you can pass `JNI_ABORT` since you're not writing to the array.

This should free the buffer in both cases.

The above assumes that the buffer is a copy and not a pinned reference. I think it is a copy however, since otherwise there wouldn't be a leak. You could find out by passing a `&isCopy` parameter to `GetByteArrayElements`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try that out tmr